# Missing causal correlation between distant parts in the brain

Tags: biophysics, causality

The Wikipage on the [Primary Motor Cortex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_motor_cortex#Movement_coding) says:

> Evarts suggested that each neuron in the motor cortex contributes to the force in a muscle. As the neuron becomes active, it sends a signal to ..., and the[n] muscle contracts.

The different muscle neurons spread in your brain as displayed in the following picture:

[image]

Now think that you move your tongue and your toe in paralell.
It might take [several milliseconds](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/12412/370) for the information to travel inside the brain from top to bottom.

> Does this mean that, if neuron fire fast enough in separate parts of the brain, that there is no causal correlation between them?

Comment: Of course, if neurons fire simultaneously, one cannot be the cause for the other. I'm not sure what the question about that here is, or why there is this picture in the question.

Comment: A good analogy is if you wanted to compute something that takes a while to compute but didn't have all the data yet. You could start many computers working on it with different values and then as new data comes in you can shut down the computers that started with bad data and when you finally get your answer someone else might be impressed with how fast you did it. But evolution favors hacks like that. But then of course there will be correlations between different parts if they want to react faster than possible and so use these hacks because it works. Slow but redundant & synthesizing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two timers can be set to fire at the same time, that alone does not imply that they do not have any causal correlation. As long as both timer triggers have a past cone big enough to contain both events, the timers can be set up by some past event

the key metric for human brain is the time of reflexive stimuli to create reactions, which involve nothing short of a tenths or hundredths of second, enough for millions of send and reply events at light speed to have place inside the radius of the brain, although probably much less at actual electrical nervous propagation speeds

Comment: So you say that there is a chance for a correlation between distant parts of the brain?

Comment: as long as coordination information can reach distant parts at slower speeds than light, then yes